# Calculating the PB of a stock in practice

Tags: equities

This is a practical problem of calculating the PB of a stock. Here is a example of `Jenapharm`, but I am not sure which terms following can be found in Bloomberg.

Jenapharm was the most respected pharmaceutical manufacturer in
East Germany.

Jenapharm, which was expected to have revenues of 230 million DM
and `earnings` before interest and taxes of `30` million DM in 1991.

The firm had a book value of assets of 110 million DM, and a `book value of equity` of `58` million DM. The `interest expenses` in 1991 is
expected to be `15` million DM. The `corporate tax rate` is `40%`.

The firm was expected to maintain sales in its niche product, a
contraceptive pill, and `grow` at `5%` a year in the long term, primarily by
expanding into the generic drug market.

The `average beta` of pharmaceutical firms traded on the Frankfurt
Stock exchange was `1.05`.

The `ten-year bond rate` in Germany at the time of this valuation was
`7%`; the `risk premium for stocks over bonds` is assumed to be `5.5%`.

Calculate the PB:

$$\textrm{Expected Net Income} = (\textrm{EBIT} - \textrm{Interest Expense})*(1-t) $$
$$= (30 - 15) *(1-0.4) = 9$$
$$\textrm{Return on Equity} = \textrm{Expected Net Income / Book Value of Equity}$$
$$ = 9 /58 = 15.52\%$$
$$\textrm{Cost on Equity} = 7\% + 1.05 (5.5\%) = 12.775\%$$
$$\textrm{Price/Book Value Ratio} = (\textrm{ROE} - g) / (r - g) $$
$$= (.1552 - .05) / (.12775 -.05) = 1.35$$

To find the data in `Bloomberg`, I have following questions:

1. Which risk free interest rate will we use? 10 year bond of respective currency?
2. For Risk premium for stocks over bonds and Expected Net Income, can we directly found those two terms in Company's information?

Comment: I've never seen this approach used. Price is usually meant to mean market value, while book is usually meant to mean accounting or economic value. What I see here is fundamentally different.

Comment: You are quite right. Because Jenapharm was not stock-market listed, they are trying to find out what the market value would have been IF IT HAD BEEN LISTED on the Frankfurt exchange (which it wasn't). So it is quite a roundabout calculation with a lot of assumptions and IFs and BUTs to estimate a hypothetical  market value.